# jquery dialog box inside div button click to call ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

This my dialog box code:

```
$("#manageGroupShow").dialog({resizable: false,draggable: false,position:['center',150],title: "Manage Group",width:"50%",modal: true,show: { effect:"drop",duration:1000,direction:"up" },hide: { effect:"drop",duration:1000,direction:"up"}});
                    });
```

manageGroupShow html code:

```
<div id="manageGroupShow" class="brdBlack" style="width: 50%;display: none;">
 </div>
```

dynamically append inside the manageGroupShow div code:

```
$("#manageGroupShow").append("<span><a     
href="javascript:cancel('+dynamicvalues')>cancel</a>"</span>")
```

this href link not fired inside the dialogbox.how to call javascript call inside dialogbox.
the span append dynamically multi times.so how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try this:     $("#manageGroupShow").append("<span><a href='javascript:cancel("+dynamicvalues+")'>cancel</a></span>")

Answer (score 1):

Open-close the quotes correctly!

```
append("<span><a href=\"javascript:cancel('dynamicvalues')\">cancel</a></span>")
```

if `dynamicvalues` is a variable

```
append("<span><a href=\"javascript:cancel('"+dynamicvalues+"')\">cancel</a></span>")
```

Answer (score 0):

What he said but use single quotes in JS string literals so that you never need to escape your html double quotes. There is never a need for double quotes in JS string literals.

```
$('#manageGroupShow')append('<span><a href="javascript:cancel('+dynamicvalues+')">cancel</a></span>');
```